# JBoss Connection Reset

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I'm used JBoss Application Server for running my web application.After I accessed again.I receive this errors :

```
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page
using constructor public
com.app.web.common.MainPage()

Root cause:

java.sql.SQLException: Io exception:
Connection reset at
oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:829)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1049)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:854)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1154)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3370)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3476)
at
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute

(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
at
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute

(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.execution.SqlExecutor.executeQuery(SqlExecutor.java:185)
at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.sqlExecuteQuery

(MappedStatement.java:221) at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback

(MappedStatement.java:189) at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForList

(MappedStatement.java:139) at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList

(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:567) at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList

(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541) at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118)
at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$3.doInSqlMapClient

(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:295) at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$3.doInSqlMapClient

(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:1) at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:200)
at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:293)
at
com.app.dao.authorization.impl.MenuDAO.selectByExample(MenuDAO.java:50)
at
com.app.dao.authorization.impl.MenuDAO.selectByExample(MenuDAO.java:1)
at
com.app.service.authorization.impl.MenuService.getParent(MenuService.java:113)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke

(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke

(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy302.getParent(Unknown Source)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke

(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke

(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy303.getParent(Unknown Source)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at
org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:416)
at
org.apache.wicket.proxy.$Proxy389.getParent(Unknown
Source) at
com.app.web.component.panel.TreeViewSubMenu.<init>(TreeViewSubMenu.java:56)
at
com.app.web.component.panel.TreeViewPanel.<init>(TreeViewPanel.java:29)
at
com.app.web.common.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:59)
at
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents

(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)
at
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:312)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process

(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke

(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at
org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Complete stack:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException:
Can't instantiate page using
constructor public 

com.app.web.common.MainPage() at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents

(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
Method) at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents

(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException:
SqlMapClient operation; SQL [];
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
--- Check the AZ_MENU.ibatorgenerated_selectByExample-InlineParameterMap.
--- Check the statement (query failed).
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset; nested
exception is 

com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
--- Check the AZ_MENU.ibatorgenerated_selectByExample-InlineParameterMap.
--- Check the statement (query failed).
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset at
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate

(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:253)
at
org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate

(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:203)
at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:293)
at
com.app.dao.authorization.impl.MenuDAO.selectByExample(MenuDAO.java:50)
at
com.app.dao.authorization.impl.MenuDAO.selectByExample(MenuDAO.java:1)
at
com.app.service.authorization.impl.MenuService.getParent(MenuService.java:113)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke

(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke

(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy302.getParent(Unknown Source)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke

(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke

(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy303.getParent(Unknown Source)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at
org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:416)
at
org.apache.wicket.proxy.$Proxy389.getParent(Unknown
Source) at
com.app.web.component.panel.TreeViewSubMenu.<init>(TreeViewSubMenu.java:56)
at
com.app.web.component.panel.TreeViewPanel.<init>(TreeViewPanel.java:29)
at
com.app.web.common.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:59)
at
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents

(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)

com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
--- Check the AZ_MENU.ibatorgenerated_selectByExample-InlineParameterMap.
--- Check the statement (query failed).
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback

(MappedStatement.java:201) at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForList

(MappedStatement.java:139) at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList

(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:567) at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList

(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541) at
com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118)
at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$3.doInSqlMapClient

(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:295) at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$3.doInSqlMapClient

(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:1) at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:200)
at
org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:293)
at
com.app.dao.authorization.impl.MenuDAO.selectByExample(MenuDAO.java:50)
at
com.app.dao.authorization.impl.MenuDAO.selectByExample(MenuDAO.java:1)
at
com.app.service.authorization.impl.MenuService.getParent(MenuService.java:113)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke

(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke

(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy302.getParent(Unknown Source)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke

(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke

(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed

(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy303.getParent(Unknown Source)
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at
org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:416)
at
org.apache.wicket.proxy.$Proxy389.getParent(Unknown
Source) at
com.app.web.component.panel.TreeViewSubMenu.<init>(TreeViewSubMenu.java:56)
at
com.app.web.component.panel.TreeViewPanel.<init>(TreeViewPanel.java:29)
at
com.app.web.common.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:59)
at
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
at
org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents

(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
at
org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents

(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any code to look for issues. Please post the oracle-ds.xml file entry here if you have used the DataSource.

We need to know a few things like:

1. The Oracle database version you are using.
2. The DB driver class (or driver version)
3. The code that makes connection

Most probably this issue is related to using a very old driver for a newer version of Oracle database.